# VBA Excel - Loop through worksheet creating tables

Tags: vba, excel

Created this macro to go through the entire worksheet and format each section as a table with a specific format.

I'm trying to loop through the entire worksheet where and format each section as a table.

Each section is separated by one blank row.

Any ideas?

```
Sub Macro8()
Range("A3:B4").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$3:$B$4"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table6"
Range("Table6[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table6").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A6:B7").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$6:$B$7"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table7"
Range("Table7[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table7").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A9:D22").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$9:$D$22"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table8"
Range("Table8[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table8").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A24:D37").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$24:$D$37"), , xlYes).Name = _
    "Table9"
Range("Table9[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table9").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
Sub MakeTables()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed

With ws

    'find last row of data in column A
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rngStart As Range
    Set rngStart = .Range("A3")

    'set counter variable for naming tables
    Dim i As Long
    i = i + 1

    Do

        'create table range
        Set rngTable = .Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlDown))

        'create table
        .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTable.Resize(rngTable.Rows.Count, rngStart.End(xlToRight).column), , xlYes).Name = "Table" & i
         'set style
        .ListObjects("Table" & i).TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"

        'find next table range start
        Set rngStart = rngTable.End(xlDown).Offset(2)

        i = i + 1

    Loop Until rngStart.Row > lRow

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great except I have some tables that are 3 columns and others that are 4. Can we modify so that it looks for the last column in each loop? The above makes every table exactly the same size leaving some data outside of the table.

Comment: @BenSimmons -  Yes, I missed that. Try my edit and see if that works for you in call cases.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman- the code above works great- thanks again. I'm running into the issue where there may be a header row that doesn't have any data in the line right underneath it. So it does the (xlDown) command and takes part of the next table's data. What would the if/then statement look like to account for this?

Comment: `IsEmpty(rngStart.Offset(1).value) then
`

Comment: @BenSimmons - DId you figure this out? If not, please post another question, and in that question please provide a screenshot sample of your data, as it will help SO understand the exact nuances of the situation.

Comment: yes sir- the edited code above was the solution I needed. Thanks for the help