# Looping through different size tables Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Previous question was answered providing me the foundation of this Loop.

[VBA Excel - Loop through worksheet creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184703/vba-excel-loop-through-worksheet-creating-tables)

However, I ran into an issue where I may have a table header with no data in the line right under it. In this case I simply want to make a table with just the header.

I have tried this code-simply assigning the row below rngStart as oneDown. And then creating an if/then to check if len(oneDown) is > 0.

```
`Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws

'find last row of data in column A
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = .Range("A3")

'set counter variable for naming tables
Dim i As Long
i = i + 1
Dim oneDown As Long
Set oneDown =rngStart.Offset(1)

Do

if Len(oneDown) > 0 Then
    'create table range
    Set rngTable = .Range(rngStart.End(xlToRight),rngStart.End(xlDown))
    'create table
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTable.Resize(rngTable.Rows.Count, rngStart.End(xlToRight).Column), , xlYes).Name = "Table" & i
    'set style
    .ListObjects("Table" & i).TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
    'find next table range start
    Set rngStart = rngTable.End(xlDown).Offset(2)
 Else
'create table range
    Set rngTable = .Range(rngStart.End(xlToRight))
    'create table
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTable.Resize(rngTable.Rows.Count, rngStart.End(xlToRight).Column), , xlYes).Name = "Table" & i
    .ListObjects("Table" & i).TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
    Set rngStart = rngTable.End(xlDown).Offset(2)

End If
    i = i + 1

Loop Until rngStart.Row > lRow

End With`
```

I'm getting the same results with my data as if I didn't have the if/then in place.

Comment: Try 
Set oneDown =rngStart.Offset(1,1)

Comment: @Silva thanks for the tip but that did not work either. Does everything look right with my if/then logic?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman any ideas?

Comment: Are your data really in a Table or just a Range? If it is a Table, it's a lot easier.

Comment: @PatricK Before this code is applied they are in a range- this code is to go through and create tables. Original Question outlining requirement is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35216879/looping-through-different-size-tables-excel-vba?noredirect=1#comment58149152_35216879

Comment: Correction- original question link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184703/vba-excel-loop-through-worksheet-creating-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change part of your code but this worked with I test it so give it a try:

```
  Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws

    'find last row of data in column A
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Set rngStart = .Range("A3")

    'set counter variable for naming tables
    Dim i As Long
    i = i + 1

    Do

Dim oneDown As String
 oneDown = rngStart.Offset(1)

'Proceed to next cell if rngstart is empty
If rngStart.Value = "" Then
   Set rngStart = rngStart.Offset(1)
ElseIf Len(oneDown) > 0 Then
    'create table range
    Set rngtable = .Range(rngStart.End(xlToRight), rngStart.End(xlDown))
    'create table
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngtable.Resize(rngtable.Rows.Count, rngStart.End(xlToRight).Column), , xlYes).Name = "Table" & i
    'set style
    .ListObjects("Table" & i).TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
    'find next table range start
    Set rngStart = rngtable.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
     i = i + 1
 Else
'create table range
    Set rngtable = .Range(rngStart.End(xlToRight), rngStart)
    'create table
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngtable.Resize(rngtable.Rows.Count, rngStart.End(xlToRight).Column), , xlYes).Name = "Table" & i
    .ListObjects("Table" & i).TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
    Set rngStart = rngtable.End(xlDown).Offset(1)
     i = i + 1
End If


    Loop Until rngStart.Row > lRow

    End With
```

Comment: I updated the answer and modified your code a bit. It worked when I tested it so give it a try and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: It works except when there isn't two spaces between desired Table headers. I've tried deleting all blank rows and then inserting a row above every row that has "CUSTOMER_" in Column A. Now, If I could just modify the rngStart to only start on those rows I would be successful.

Comment: I updated it to account for multiple or single blank rows between tables. Should resolve that issue without the need for the customer_ identifier.

Comment: @Jonathan- works like a charm! Thanks for the solution!